# Как отобразить обьект класса в MainWindow?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qgroupbox

Есть класс `FirstWindow`, который наследует класс `QMainWindow`. Также есть класс `FirstWiget`, который наследует класс `QGroupBox`.

Как сделать так, чтобы объект класса `FirstWiget` отобразился на открытом окне класса `FirstWindow`?

```
class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        # какой то код код
        pass

class FirstWiget(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        #какой то код код
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWiget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class FirstWiget(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setTitle('FirstWiget') 
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(99, 125, 187); 
            border: 2px solid #ff2b3f;;
        ''')
        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        #какой то код код
        pass
        

class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  
        self.setWindowTitle('FirstWindow')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)        
        
        self.initUI()
        
        layout.addWidget(self.firstWiget)
        
    def initUI(self):
        # какой то код код
        self.firstWiget = FirstWiget()
               
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]